# How to load several days data from a folder containing huge amount of data on HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

Suppose on hdfs I have a folder `/usr/data/`, which containing a lot of days' data organized with date, like `/usr/data/date=xxxx`. I want to load one week's data in zeppelin notebook, so what I did is

```
val data = spark.read.parque("/usr/data/").filter("DATE>='2020-06-05' && 'DATE<=2020-06-12'")
```

However, since the whole data size of `/usr/data/` is too huge, the loading cannot be done, is there any method to just load the one week's data, without loading the whole folder first? Thanks

Comment: Misprint in filter condition - quote is located after &&, must be after =.

Answer (score 0):

Spark optimizer would take care of it and won't load whole folder.

- As your data is partitioned on `date` column spark won't load all the data from `/usr/data` instead only load the matching directories that fall in your filter query.
- you can check execution plan to view what are the directories (in `PartitionFilters` section) getting loaded using **`.explain()`**.

**`Example:`**

```
val data = spark.read.parquet("/usr/data/").filter(col("date">="2020-06-05" &&col("date") <= "2020-06-12")
data.explain()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I hope the spark optimizer could work. It is just if I copy one week data to a separate folder I could load them. If I use the filter on the whole folder, the load always fail. I am using spark 2.1.1, any idea on this?